# Need a workaround for Adobe SnapSVG-animator running in React.js

Tags: reactjs, animation, svg, snap.svg

SnapSVG extension for Adobe Animate.cc 2017 is able to create interactivity and animations for the web.  I'm currently trying to use an exported SnapSVG Adobe Animate.cc project in my REACT JS WebApplication.

**What I did so far**

1. Published html file from a SnapSVG project(Animate.cc 2017)
2. Copyed custom json file created from the SnapSVG project in animate.cc in my React app.
3. Installed SnapSVG from npm install in my React App.
4. Imported the js file copyed from the html publication created from animate.cc by importing the code. ( SnapSVG-animator isn't available in npm)
5. The custom json file from animate.cc/snap svg project is loaded async and will be added to the SVGAnim(SnapSVGAnimator.min.js) function object which will create the svg animation in de browser.

**The code**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import snapsvg from 'snapsvg';
import { SVGAnim } from './SnapSVGAnimator.min.js';

let jsonfile = "circle.json", 
                responseType: 'json';

componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(jsonfile)
      .then(response => {
        const json = response.request.responseText;
        const animatedSVG = new SVGAnim(json);
      });
  }
```

**Problem**

The SnapSVGAnimator.min.js creates warnings and errors when it's imported in the JSX file. Looks like something going wrong with compiling these code.

✖ 1557 problems (110 errors, 1447 warnings)[image]

Comment: It looks like you are using eslint or some other linter to check minified code - that can't work. You should exclude any minified code from linting.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I putted the minified code in an unminify.js file but same large amount of warnings and errors appears.

Comment: You can't lint the minified code as it is not beautiful at all, it works and is small. So you need to lint the unminified code or exclude the minified version from linting.

Comment: I've added .eslintignore file and ignored SnapSVGAnimator.min.js from linting. Errors and warning disappeared successfully.  Now a new error appears in snapsvg.js related to this issue https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/341

Comment: Now added snapsvg-cjs instead of snapsvg from NPM and snapsvg now works properly. Only problem now is the errors appears again `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _SnapSVGAnimator.SVGAnim is not a constructor`

Comment: That is another question and therefore should be asked in full detail in a new question. It looks like some constructor is missing, maybe the referenced class is not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install the following libraries:

```
npm install --save snapsvg-animator snapsvg-cjs
```

given your json is at ../../public/myAnimation.json do the following:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import SVGAnim from "snapsvg-animator";
import "snapsvg-cjs";
const myAnimation = require('../../public/myAnimation.json'); //import your json


function Home() {

  const svg = new SVGAnim(
    myAnimation,
    200, //width
    220, //height
    40 //fps
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const container = document.getElementById('animation');
    container.appendChild(svg.s.node);
  });

  return (
    <div id="main">
      <div id="animation"/>
    </div>
  )



};
export default Home;
```

I am using react hooks because it is all the rage ☺ but it's working with "render" and "componentDidMount" all the same.